# Get the selected row in DataGridViewRow event in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I am using the `DataGridView` bound to a database. I have a button that is disabled.  When a row is selected, not by clicking in a cell but on the row selection pane, I want to respond to an event and enable that button.

Answer (score 3):

Well, there's the [RowHeaderMouseClick event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowheadermouseclick.aspx). From there, you can get e.RowIndex to determine which row the click occurred on.

Answer (score 2):

```
protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        AddRowSelectToGridView(gridView);
        base.Render(writer);
    }

    private void AddRowSelectToGridView(GridView gv)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (GridViewRow row in gv.Rows)
            {
                row.Attributes["onmouseover"] = "this.style.cursor='hand';this.style.textDecoration='underline';";
                row.Attributes["onmouseout"] = "this.style.textDecoration='none';";
                row.Attributes.Add("onclick", Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(gv, "Select$" + row.RowIndex.ToString(), true));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }

    }
```

try this code,u can select the row..

Answer (score 0):

Arguably the 'correct' event to use to detect when a DataGridView row is selected is `SelectionChanged`.

```
dataGridView1.SelectionChanged += new EventHandler(dataGridView1_SelectionChanged);

void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // code that happens after selection
}
```

The problem with this event is that the event signature only has a plain EventArgs with not special information about the DataGridView. Also this responds to any source of the selection changing, not *only* the row header being selected.

Depending on your exact needs the bemused's answer of `RowHeaderMouseClick` could well be better.